# JaVers - how to add extra fields to reference entity in JSON

Tags: java, audit, javers

I was trying to add **JaVers** library to my current project. And I wondered Is there any ways to add to reference entity fields some field which will be shown instead of Id when I fetch changes?
For example snapshot of User class:

```
{
   "owner": {
     "entity": "Owner",
     "cdoId": 1
   },
   "username": "TMP",...
}
```

and if I change Owner reference and fetch for changes, I will get:

```
ReferenceChange{ 'owner' changed from 'Owner/1' to 'Owner/2' }
```

What I want is some thing like:

```
{
   "owner": {
     "entity": "Owner",
     "cdoId": 1
     "cdoName": "OWN"
},
   "username": "TMP",...
```

and changes like this:

```
ReferenceChange{ 'owner' changed from 'OWN' to 'FOO' }
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I`m using Javers 3.11.3

Answer (score 1):

You can't add more fields to a Reference. In JaVers, a Reference is just a global identifier of an entity. Try to describe the problem you have, maybe there is a better solution than changing javers-core model.